# flex cout string crash

Tags: c++, flex-lexer

when i try to print a string(cout) in a flex program, the program crashs.
My .l file looks like this:

```
%{
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>

    using namespace std;
%}

%option noyywrap

%%
.   {string str = "hi"; cout << str;}
%%

int main(){
    yylex();

    return 0;
}
```

I compile the generated files with g++. My flex version is 2.5.35.

When i simply write `cout << "hi";` the program does not crash.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: and what is your `g++` version? I can't reproduce the problem on `flex 2.5.35` and `g++ 4.9.2`

Comment: my g++ version is 4.9.3

Comment: Are there any crash logs?

Comment: What do the generated files look like? _Divide and conquer._

Comment: [link](http://pastebin.com/Tc3dTauj) This is the generated file. In line 740 is my `cout`. There is no crash log... the program just crashes without any message.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your post to include any additional information you have to your question. Avoid adding this in the comments, as they are harder to read and can be deleted easier. The edit button for your post is just below the post's tags.

Comment: Please also include the exact invocations of flex and gcc used to produce the executabke, and the input which causes the failure. And some description of what you mean bt "crash" -- is it a segfault? Or does it just terminate without output?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work with flex version 2.5.39.

You can preprocess the generated file with g++ -E and look at the output to see if the translation of

```
{string str = "hi"; cout << str;}
```

has not changed.

Comment: I have download your generated file and it compiles and runs fine with  g++ 4.8.4 and clang++ 3.6. It outputs as many "blubhi" as there are in the input. valgrind only reports some memory leaks related to the flex buffer. So your code is fine for me.